# Capistrano Deploy fails with git: 'info' is not a git command

Tags: git, deployment, capistrano

I setup a new project with Capistrano and although i can successfully run `cap deploy:setup` if i try to deploy my project I get the error below

```
→ cap deploy
  * executing `deploy'
  * executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    executing locally: "git info git@github.com:foo/Baconalytics.git  -rHEAD"
git: 'info' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean one of these?
    init
    mailinfo
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
```

I have several other projects that deploy fine from the same machine however this one will not. Git is installed on my host and target. Does anyone know troubleshooting steps I can take?

My deploy.rb file:

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
set :application, "baconalyitcs"
set :repository, "git@github.com:foo/Baconalytics.git"
set :scm_command, "git"
set :deploy_to, "/root/baconalytics"
set :branch, "master"
set :user, "root"
set :use_sudo, false
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true


set :deploy_via, :remote_cache



set :ruby_prefix, "/usr/bin/ruby"
set :deploy_user, "#{ENV['USER']}"

role :worker, "xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com", :primary => true
role :namenode, "xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com"

after "deploy", "deploy:bundle_gems"
after "deploy", "deploy:print_success_banner"


namespace :deploy do

  task :print_success_banner do
    puts "---------------------------------------------------"
    puts "--------------- DEPLOY SUCCEEDED ------------------"
    puts "---------------------------------------------------"
  end


  task :bundle_gems, :roles => [:worker] do
    run "rm -rf /mnt/app/current/vendor/cache; true"
    run "if [ -f /mnt/app/current/Gemfile.lock ]; then rm /mnt/app/current/Gemfile.lock; fi;"

    cmd = [
           "cd #{current_path}",
           "#{ruby_prefix}/bundle install",
          ].join(" && ")
    run cmd
  end
end

task :ssh do
  role = ARGV[1]
  servers = @roles[role.to_sym].servers rescue @roles[role.to_sym]
  puts instances = `rake ec2:din` unless server
  instances = instances.split("\n") unless server
  system "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@#{(server || instances[ssh_server.to_i].split("\t")[2])}"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update after posting the deploy.rb:**

You have to use `set :scm, "git"` so that it recognizes that you are using git. Hope that helps.

Note, my initial statement on confusion between `git` and `svn` is right. It was thinking it was an svn repo, but since you changed the `scm_command` alone to `git`, it was trying `git info`. `scm_command` I think has to be used only when the scm command is not on path.

---

`info` is not a git subcommand like it says.

```
git: 'info' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean one of these?
    init
    mailinfo
```

clearly, git is installed and fine, but `info` is not a git command. ( But svn has it, any confusion between git and svn? )

Comment: no, i'm not confused about the difference between git and svn. I am confused why this Capistrano project would call this non-existant command but my others will not.

Comment: @Schneems - so you downvote me when you haven't even given the cap file /snippet? Good luck with people helping you out.

Comment: Your answer has yet to prove helpful. When it gets changed I'll up-vote your answer, as well as any constructive comments you leave. If you need a Capistrano file, or snippet please ask, you're the domain expert here, right? I WANT to give you points, almost as much as I want to get this problem solved, PLEASE give me a reason.

Comment: you're exactly right i had `set :scm_command, "git"` but not `set :scm "git"` thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Try installing [`git-info`](https://github.com/knu/git-info)?

Comment: i don't need git-info for any of my other capistrano deploys, why would i need it for this project?

Comment: that came off as sarcastic, but is a genuine question.

Answer (score 0):

Following the previous reply:

```
which git-info
```

/usr/bin/git-info

```
rpm -qf /usr/bin/git-info
```

git-extras-4.1.0-1.fc23.noarch

we need install git-extras at least in Fedora Linux